# How to control the image of an object in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, image, oop, graphics, flash-cs3

I have an object which is coded in a .as file, let's call it a widget, in `widget.as`. It is listed in the library as a MovieClip and is in fact a MovieClip. How can I, from the code in `widget.as`,  overlay an image (Bitmap) from the library on it so that the Widget has four parts which can be switched between two different styles independently.

As an alternative, I could make a frame in the MovieClip of Widget for each possibility and make the code switch what frame I am on.

This must work in Adobe Flash CS3 and with ActionScript 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the image you want to show on top of it, and already have that split in four, then you could do something like this:

```
var tl:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
var tr:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
var bl:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
var br:Bitmap = new Bitmap();

addChild(tl);
addChild(tr);
addChild(bl);
addChild(br);
```

Comment: how do I select what bitmaps go on it? How do I place the bitmaps? How can I change them later?